# How to store chat history using langchain conversationalRetrievalQA chain in a Next JS app?

Tags: next.js, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, pinecone

Im creating a text document QA chatbot, Im using [Langchainjs](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchainjs) along with [OpenAI](https://openai.com/) LLM for creating embeddings and Chat and [Pinecone](https://www.pinecone.io/) as my vector Store.

See Diagram:
[image]

After successfully uploading embeddings and creating an index on pinecone. I am using Next JS app to communicate with OpenAI and Pinecone.

The current structure of my App is like so:

1: Frontend -> user inputs a `question` and makes a POST call to a NEXT js server API route `/ask`

2: The server func looks like the following:

```
const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
        new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
        { pineconeIndex })

const model = new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0.5, modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo' })

const memory = new ConversationSummaryMemory({
    memoryKey: 'chat_history',
    llm: new ChatOpenAI({ modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo', temperature: 0 }),
})

const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
    model,
    vectorStore.asRetriever(),
    {
        memory,
    }
)

const result = await chain.call({
    question,
})

return NextResponse.json({ data: result.text })
```

**The ISSUE:** The Chatbot never has access to any history because the **memory** always ONLY has ONLY the latest message in storage.

```
console.log('memory:', await memory.loadMemoryVariables({}))
```

I also tried `BufferMemory` and same Issue, the memory buffer only has ONLY the message just asked, if new query comes in the buffer is cleared and the new query is the only message in memory.

I may be unclear on how exactly to correctly store the history so the
`const result = await chain.call({question,})` call has access to the previous info

**UPDATE**: I have successfully used Upstash Redis-Backed Chat Memory with langchain, however still curious if it is possible to store messages using User Browser?

Comment: The related documentation talks about external memory for history : `await chain.call({question: "Was that nice?",chat_history: chatHistory,});` but tbh I didn't try it out: https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/index_related_chains/conversational_retrieval#externally-managed-memory

Comment: We managed to store the history with `RedisChatMessageHistory` in `BufferMemory`. Does Pinecone have a similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am using same exact stack as you (Next.js, Pinecone, Langchain ConversationalRetrievalQAChain) and I fought with this exact issue for a while.

Eventually I resorted to the below 'hack' which does work, basically capturing the history in a `messages` array which I shove into the end of the prompt. To my knowledge this is not all that different than how LangChain's 'Memory' components are supposed to work so I don't feel terrible doing this.

Here is a trimmed down version of my main handler function. Take note of line starting with `queryText+='\nIf necessary ...`

```
export async function POST(req: Request) {
    const { messages } = await req.json();
    let queryText = messages[messages.length - 1].content;
    
    queryText+='\nIf necessary, utilize the below chat history as additional context:'+JSON.stringify(messages);
    
    const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
            streamingModel,
            vectorStore.asRetriever(),
            {
                returnSourceDocuments: true,
                questionGeneratorChainOptions: {
                    llm: nonStreamingModel,
                },
            }

    const { stream, handlers } = LangChainStream();
    chain.call({ question: queryText }, [handlers]).catch(console.error)

    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `returnMessages:true` property of `ConversationSummaryMemory`:

```
const memory = new ConversationSummaryMemory({
  memoryKey: 'chat_history',
  llm: new ChatOpenAI({ modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo', temperature: 0 }),
  returnMessages:true
})
```

this is the code for `loadMemoryVariables` from

```
async loadMemoryVariables(_) {
        if (this.returnMessages) {
            const result = {
                [this.memoryKey]: [new this.summaryChatMessageClass(this.buffer)],
            };
            return result;
        }
        const result = { [this.memoryKey]: this.buffer };
        return result;
    }
```

if you set `returnMessages:true` it will return `this.summaryChatMessageClass(this.buffer)` object otherwise it just returns a string.